# Is there a way to send push notifications from an Android device to another one?

Tags: android, notifications, push

I want to create a notification app. Everytime my phone receives a notification from an app (for example the Messaging app), it should send the same notification to another android device which doesn't have the same app installed.

Do you maybe know from where to start?

Thank you

Comment: [You could start here.](http://bit.ly/1zclTRw)

Answer (score 0):

first you will need a server. (one.com) or somethink else. there are some Servers that costs nothink, too. 
Then you create an app to send messages to the server and another app to recieve (update all 3min and send a request to the server). You can also make your request to recieve messages with a google-service.

As Sample:

1.your Broadcast-app makes a httprequest (make a post to a .php site with an id and the message)

2.your php site on the server writes the message to mysql-table ($ message=$_POST["message"] and $id=$_POST['id'] => mysqli_query($database,"INSERT INTO table ('id','message') values ($id,$message)");

3.your recieving app calls another php-site with http-request (maybe runs in background and all 5 min. makes a http-request to the site with id

4.the second php: (SELECT message from table where id=$_POST['id']; if there is a message post the message, else post an error--maybe "false"

5.the app gets from the httprequest the message or the string false (if (answer!="false") make_a_push())

So what you need to learn is php,java http-request,mysql and putting it together. this is one solution, there are some else to do this.